# Unknown Tag Cores in Solr.XML

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I'm attempting to initialize a multicore solr server using Solr 3.5 and I'm getting this error.

Here's the stack trace I'm seeing.

```
    2011-12-15 22:44:59.166:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-12-15 22:44:59.197:WARN::Config error at <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">|    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0"/>|    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1"/>|  </cores> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag: cores
2011-12-15 22:44:59.197:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag: cores
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:264)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:214)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:974)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Comment: Weird. Can you post the contents of `solr.xml`? Is it in your solr.home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the solr tag as root of your solr.xml file. It should be something like this:

```
<solr>
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
        <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0"/>
        <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1"/>
    </cores>
</solr>
```

You might want to take a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin).

**UPDATE**
I just noticed your log says jetty is trying to read the solr.xml as jetty configuration file. You should check how you're running jetty. If you want more help please add some more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually do have the <solr> tag in place.  I'm having this problem with the default multicore example.

Comment: Weird, in your log file there is no root. Anyway, I noticed one more thing, please see my updated answer.